# Collapse all for xml elements in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Collapse all not working properly in eclipse for xml elements. Sometimes it is not collapsing child elements. I want a feature exactly like in notepad++ where you can collapse all the xml elements.

Comment: Where in the UI do you mean?

Comment: When I open the xml files in xml editor.

Comment: Raised a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526387

Comment: I think this needs a screenshot. Just saying it’s in the XML Editor is not specific enough.